# AngularJS ng-repeat long array, sorted by date but limiting to only 10 rows

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got a long array with over 100 objects. Each object has a `member.date`, but some are `null`, and some have a date string.

`<tr ng-repeat="(k, member) in provider.allMembers | orderBy:'ended':true" ng-if="member.ended">`

my problem is I only want to show the latest 10, but when I add `limitTo:10` I get zero results (because the first entry that is displayed is the 42nd object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own filter which check if the property is null or not and returns what you want :)

eg. https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resorting the array by end date, then simply limiting the `ng-repeat` to 10.

```
// sort all members by ended date
$rootScope.provider.allMembers.sort(function(a,b){
   return new Date(b.ended) - new Date(a.ended);
});
```

then using this ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(k, member) in provider.allMembers | limitTo:10">
```